# How to disable delete and update post options to the Blogger API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, blogger

I am using the Blogger Javascript API to retrieve my blog posts and anyone can easily see API key in the view-source, and it can be used for deleting and updating posts. I would like somehow to prevent others from doing so, is there any way to do that?

Comment: It depends on what's being displayed with the key... Is your request similar to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16147476/4929742 ?

Comment: @Bilel It makes Ajax request with the following link:
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOG_ID/posts?&key=API_KEY

Comment: From where are you doing this? A custom dashboard/backend ? If you need sensitive operations like Delete/Update why doing that with javascript? who "others" other using having access to your dashboard... please clarify that

Comment: @Bilel I am doing this from my blog home page, and on a sidebar on almost every page. I don't have access to backend stuff, it's a Blogger's website and it doesn't allow me to do the backend. I don't need those two operations, I only retrieve blog posts. Javascript because it is, I guess, the only way to do so on Blogger websites. Only I have access to the Blogger dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if someone got your api key he can't make any changes to your blog, because [updating](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/update) or [deleting](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/delete) posts requests requires [authorizing](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#auth) with OAuth 2.0

> If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an individual's private data), then the application must provide an OAuth 2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to.